# How to specify that a SQLCLR table valued function is ordered?

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I have a sqlclr table valued function that has a prototype like

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[some_func]
(...)
RETURNS TABLE (
        [order_id]      INT NULL,
        [value1]        VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        [value2]        INT NULL
)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [some_db].[MyProject].[some_func]
```

The actual function doesn't matter. Now I know that my function always returns the results in sequential order based on `order_id`.

I'm using this function and joining it against a table which is indexed on `order_id` and when I join the two and look at the plan I see that the join has caused a spill to do a sort.

Now, I found this article which told me that I could use modify the prototype and specify order.

http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/sql-server-2008-ordered-sqlclr-table-valued-functions/

Changing the prototype manually does produce the desired result

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[some_func]
(...)
RETURNS TABLE (
        [order_id]      INT NULL,
        [value1]        VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        [value2]        INT NULL
)
ORDER(order_id asc)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [some_db].[MyProject].[some_func]
```

This version of the func does not need to sort and no spill happens in tempdb. 
However, we regularly deploy our sql project through SSDT, and everytime we do it automatically generates the prototype. I have no way to control what get set. Is there an option in my cs function so that I can specify that the result of `some_func` is ordered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, SSDT does not have a mechanism (i.e. Attribute such as `SqlFacet`) for supporting this option (nor several others). Your options are:

1. Create a post-deployment SQL Script to issue an `ALTER FUNCTION` statement that is exactly what you want it to be. Just add a SQL script to your project, and set its "Build Action" to "PostDeploy".
2. Generate the DDL (i.e. `CREATE FUNCTION...`) yourself and use a "Post-build event" (under Project Properties | Build Events) to execute the SQL via SQLCMD
3. Create your own attribute that you can mark the function with, and then create a Deployment Contributor ("Build Action" = "Deployment Extension Configuration"). This would allow it to be handled inline via SSDT, but seems to be a fair bit of work.

Other options not supported via SSDT (please vote for them to be supported via the following links :-):

- [Implement OnNullCall property in SqlFunctionAttribute for RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2304309/implement-onnullcall-property-in-sqlfunctionattribute-for-returns-null-on-null-input-sqlclr)
- [SSDT - Support T-SQL parameter defaults for SQLCLR objects via the SqlFacet attribute when generating the publish and create SQL scripts](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1571539/ssdt-support-t-sql-parameter-defaults-for-sqlclr-objects-via-the-sqlfacet-attribute-when-generating-the-publish-and-create-sql-scripts)

Due to all of these unsupported options, I rarely use SSDT for the actual deployment, and when I do, I use Post Deployment SQL scripts to do the `ALTER` statements (though they are not dynamic, which is why it would be better to be supported via an Attribute in the code). Most of the time I just use my own deployment script ( **.CMD** ) that I trigger as a Post Build event.

---

P.S. I have now submitted a Microsoft Connection Suggestion for this particular feature:
[SSDT - Support ORDER clause for SQLCLR TVFs via the SqlFunction attribute when generating the publish and create SQL scripts](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3124449)

Comment: A bit sad, but yeah I can use a alter function step.